# How to set my application to always run as root OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing an OSX application that some features of it requires ROOT privileges 
I figured out how to debug my app as root (simply in schemes).

But I want users to run it as Root so they will have access to its features.

How can I do this??

Comment: Run as root or run with `sudo`? There's a difference. I'm assuming you want to run with `sudo`. Running as root means running it under the root user account.

Comment: Why would you want this? Just log in as root.

Comment: - I have some functionality , that requires su prieveleges there,

Comment: @9000 yes I want my users to run it as sudo.

Comment: i have install helperTool successfully, still macosxvpn code not run on Debug Process as (Me). can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not run desktop applications as root. The Mac OS X frameworks are not intended to be used this way, and undesirable behavior will result (e.g, files/folders owned by root in the user's Library; process not responsive to "force quit"; potential security vulnerabilities).

Use [Authorization Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/02authconcepts/authconcepts.html) to run specific, limited privileged operations as root.

Comment: Indeed. The correct way to do this is request authorization for specific tasks or to log in as root. There is no reason any user land app should run with root privileges constantly. That just gives the user root and opens things for disaster. Both external and user blunder.

Comment: It looks like exactly what I want , just didn't understand about tasks: when I call a method : I can put it there on vompletion block , and then run my restricted function ?

Comment: i am using this  https://github.com/halo/macosvpn code in osx Application, this code work only when i set root and compile from Xcode, but when i run myapplication.app file not working, not store password in System Keychain. Furthermore i have install Helpertool, still no progress

Comment: i have install helperTool successfully, still macosxvpn socurce code not store password in System Keychain  on Debug Process as (Me). Can anyone help me?

Comment: @SawanCool You seem to be lost. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Is it possible to run the privileged operations as root without need of manual re-authorizing/authenticating (after the first time). I have a small bash script that need's to run under root, but using `sudo` I have to re-type password almost every time it's run. Is there something like _permanent sudo_ in Authorization Services?

Comment: sometimes developers like me needs to execute some apps with `sudo` so don't tell such things like `mac os x is not intended to be used in that way`... osx is unix bases OS and its normal to use `root` permissions sometimes. see also (AppleSupport)[https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012]

Comment: @ToKra As you said yourself, it's normal to use root privileges **sometimes** - *e.g,* by using Authorization Services to run specific operations as root. It is not normal to run an entire desktop application as root all the time.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a typical OS X application bundle, you can run it as root in the Terminal with:

```
sudo /Applications/YourAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/YourAppName
```

You could save a file containing just this, and name it YourAppLauncher.command, and it would be double-clickable from the Finder.

Or, in AppleScript:

```
do shell script "/Applications/YourAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/YourAppName" ¬
    with administrator privileges user name "username" password "password"
```

Then save that as an Application to launch your app as root. It won't prompt for a password (if you want it to, remove everything after *with administrator privileges*.

Comment: And I can upload it to appStore with this ?

Comment: Definitely not. You'd need to programmatically grant privileged access via appropriate frameworks, and even then I don't even know one way or the other if they let anything at all that uses privileged access into the Mac App Store. I'm thinking they don't but can't say so authoritatively.

Comment: can you explain in detail regarding AppleScript as you wrote above i write as you suggested above under BUILD PHASES-> RUN SCRIPT .. but it is giving me errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local server and keep it running in /Library/LaunchDaemons. This will let the server auto startup and gain the root privilege. I found a good article talking about this.

https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/adding-startup-scripts-to-launch-daemon-on-mac-os-x-sierra-10-12-6-7e0318c74de1

Comment: I ended app nesting applications, one app as launcher asks for privileges and open the needed app as root.